# Hola como puedo validar un numero cuilt ?en java usando neatbeants

Tags: java

Quiero validar un numero cuilt(20-40537735-8)ejemplo.
en jaba para neatbeans de la manera más sencilla de hacerlo

Comment: Hola te sugerimos agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask]. Si eres de Argentina me imagino que te refieres al "CUIL.

Comment: investiga sobre regex